# mysql определить на какой странице находится запись

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос, который группирует даты по дням и выводит последнюю запись за определенный день. Нужно изменить запрос так, чтобы можно было определить на какой странице находится запись

```sql
SELECT e.subject, 
       DATE(e.time) AS time
FROM   entries e 
       JOIN (SELECT Max(id) AS latestID 
             FROM   entries 
             GROUP  BY DATE(time)) AS dates 
         ON e.id = dates.latestid
```

**Так получаю кол-во всех страниц (по 30 записей на страницу):**

```sql
SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*)/30) FROM entries WHERE pid = 0
```

**Структура базы:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `uniqid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_reply` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `edited` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `edited_by` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `subject` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `category` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `hp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `ip` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `tags` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `show_signature` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `email_notification` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `marked` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `locked` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sticky` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `views` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `spam` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `spam_check_status` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `edit_key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `tid` (`tid`),
    INDEX `category` (`category`),
    INDEX `pid` (`pid`),
    INDEX `sticky` (`sticky`)
)
```

Comment: страницы идут в порядке убывания, т.е. из 150 страниц - 150 страница будет первой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подойдет?

```sql
SELECT @s:=@s+1 AS AUTO_INCREMENT, FLOOR((@s-1)/30)+1 AS pageNum, e.subject, 
       DATE(e.time) AS TIME
FROM   entries e 
       JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS latestID 
             FROM   entries 
             GROUP  BY DATE(time)) AS dates 
         ON e.id = dates.latestid 
         , (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s;
```

Я объясню:

- `(SELECT @s:= 0)` позволяет добавить счетчик записей
- `@s:=@s+1` - порядковый номер записи в запросе
- `FLOOR((@s-1)/30)+1` номер страницы, на которой запись будет расположена (где `30` - кол-во записей на странице, `+1` - счетчик страниц не должен начинаться с нуля)

Имея эти данные в PHP можно все остальное выяснить, если занести запрос в массив: отсортировать в обратном порядке, узнать номер страницы у последней записи, отобразить с конца в начало...

Comment: В принципе должно сработать, но сейчас запрос исполняется неправильно, как добавить, чтобы выбирал сообщения с pid =0 , а не все вложенные?

Comment: SELECT @s:=@s+1 AS AUTO_INCREMENT, FLOOR((@s-1)/30)+1 AS pageNum, e.subject, 
       DATE(e.time) AS TIME
FROM   entries e 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS latestID 
             FROM   entries
             GROUP  BY DATE(time)) AS dates 
         ON e.id = dates.latestid 
         , (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
         WHERE e.pid = 0

изменил так, LEFT JOIN уместен тут? вроде работает

Comment: Ну раз работает, то вопрос отвечен? ;) Ну а насчет уместности - это от задачи зависит. Получается, что если использовать `LEFT JOIN`, то будет выводиться все из `entries`. Тогда выяснение последней записи по дням не нужно...